# Will enabling `mod_status` in apache slow my app down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

If I wanted to to monitor response time of my requests should I use Apache's [`mod_status`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) or should I use Passenger's `passenger-status` monitoring tools?

My concern is that enabling `mod_status` will slow my apps down, but I don't have anyway to compare since I need to run `mod_status` to benchmark the performance.

By the way Passenger's passenger-status only gives me some trivial info like so:

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 0
active   = 0
inactive = 0
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Domains -----------
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this should have any impact on Apache's performance.

Pretty much all the module is doing is taking internal state that the server already has — i.e. it knows how many workers it has spawned, what they're doing and so on — and rendering it to HTML.

Comment: Agreed. See http://www.philchen.com/2008/06/02/apache-20-mod_status-effects-on-performance-server-resources

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information: I have a apache version 2.2.16 running receiving live traffic (so not a benchmark). No ruby or passenger, but with mod_fastcgi.

At 175req/s the server kept up, at 370 it was running at a load of 8-10.

After disabling the `Extended` status (but keeping mod_status enabled), the load dropped below 2.

Disabling mod_status completely did not make any difference over disabling Extended (load may already be too low to see a difference now).